# Java 2D game, updating rectangles

Tags: java, rectangles

I have coded a simple 2D Java game where there is a overhead view of a player on a 2D map that moves with the keyboard arrow input (up, down, left, right), my Play class that holds all of my game code is made up of a few methods, the main ones being render which draws everything onto the screen such as the actual player and map and update which deals with the keyboard inputs, moving the player and updating images.

Here is my code for my play class:

```
     imports are here
    public class Play extends BasicGameState{
    Animation bucky, movingUp, movingDown, movingLeft, movingRight;
    Image worldMap;
    int[] duration = {200, 200};//how long frame stays up for
    float buckyPositionX = 0;
    float buckyPositionY = 0;
    float shiftX = buckyPositionX + 320;//keeps user in the middle of the screem
    float shiftY = buckyPositionY + 160;//the numbers are half of the screen size
    java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Float rectOne = new Rectangle2D.Float(shiftX, shiftY,90,90);
    java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Float rectTwo = new Rectangle2D.Float(500 + buckyPositionX, 330 + buckyPositionY, 210, 150);
    public Play(int state){
    }   
    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{
          worldMap = new Image("res/world.png");
          Image[] walkUp = {new Image("res/b.png"), new Image("res/b.png")}; //these are the images to be used in the "walkUp" animation
          Image[] walkDown = {new Image("res/f.png"), new Image("res/f.png")};
          Image[] walkLeft = {new Image("res/l.png"), new Image("res/l.png")};
          Image[] walkRight = {new Image("res/r.png"), new Image("res/r.png")};
    movingUp = new Animation(walkUp, duration, false);
    movingDown = new Animation(walkDown, duration, false);  
    movingLeft = new Animation(walkLeft, duration, false);  
    movingRight = new Animation(walkRight, duration, false);
    bucky = movingDown;//facing screen initially on startup
    }
    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{
    worldMap.draw(buckyPositionX, buckyPositionY);//position 0,0
    bucky.draw(shiftX, shiftY);//makes him appear at center of map
    g.fillRect((float)rectOne.getX(), (float)rectOne.getY(), (float)rectOne.getWidth(), (float)rectOne.getHeight());
    g.fillRect((float)rectTwo.getX(), (float)rectTwo.getY(), (float)rectTwo.getWidth(), (float)rectTwo.getHeight());
}
    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)throws SlickException{
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    //up
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){
        bucky = movingUp;//changes the image to his back
        buckyPositionY += 2;;//increase the Y coordinates of bucky (move him up)
        if(buckyPositionY>162){//if I reach the top 
            buckyPositionY -= 2;//stops any further movement in that direction
        }
    }
    //down
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){
        bucky = movingDown;
        buckyPositionY -= 2;
        if(buckyPositionY<-550){
            buckyPositionY += 2;//basically change the direction if + make -
    }}
    //left
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){
        bucky = movingLeft;
        buckyPositionX += 2;
        if(buckyPositionX>324){
            buckyPositionX -= 2;//delta * .1f
    }}
    //right
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){
        bucky = movingRight;
        buckyPositionX -= 2;
        if(buckyPositionX<-776){
            buckyPositionX += 2;
    }}}   
    public int getID(){
        return 1;
    }}
```

I need to update rectTwo by putting it inside my update class which will update its position but am having problems writing the code to do this, could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Specify the question. Getting rectTwo into the update function (assuming you meant function rather then class) is done by writing: rectTwo in your update function (It's part of your class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean update method ?

What kind of update do you want to do ? his position ? did you try something like that in your update method:

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)
throws SlickException {

```
Input input = gc.getInput();
//up
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){
     rectTwo.setRect(float x, float y, float w, float h) ;
     ....
```

y could be rectTwo.getY() + 2 depending of ur own rules